# ClassNotFoundException in Quick Start VM

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am trying to execute Java jar, but facing issue with classpath. What can I try to resolve this?

```
[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ ls -rlt Kafka_Consumer.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 2227 Mar  9 03:28 Kafka_Consumer.jar

[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ java -cp Kafka_Consumer.jar org.abc.cde.KafkaConsumerTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer
    at org.abc.cde.KafkaConsumerTest.main(KafkaConsumerTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Below is my Java code snippet without any error:

```
 package org.abc.cde;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
 
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        //consumer properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test-group");
        
        //using auto commit
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
 
        //string inputs and outputs
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 
        //kafka consumer object
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
 
        //subscribe to topic
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("my-topic"));
 
        //infinite poll loop
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

There are no compile time errors.

Comment: Can you show your hole main method? The error happens on line 27 and in your code snippet I can't see this line.

Comment: Edited my question by adding complete Java code. Could you please check?

Comment: There is no `org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.class` file in `Kafka_Consumer.jar`. Where is `Kafka_Consumer.jar` coming from ? There is no *kafka.jar* on your classpath ?

Comment: I have added these Jars in my Eclipse Build path : kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar
lz4-1.3.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
snappy-java-1.1.2.4.jar.   Could you please confirm if I need to add kafka.jar also in my build path? Thanks in Advance